# How to check app logs on Android

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to check the application logs on the mobile device while the user is logging in. I am using a local storage mechanism of IBM Worklight to remember the user id (Remember Me functionality). Now to check if everything is going fine, I need the logs on the client side. Is there any mobile app that monitors the logs of the other apps for Android or any other way to view the error messages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what do you mean here... place `WL.Logger.debug` calls in key areas in your code and inspect the LogCat view in Eclipse (while the device is connected with a cable) in order to review the printed logs.

Comment: Idan, We have deployed the code into the server. Now trying to access the app from mobile (no eclipse or LogCat in the picture). For example, the debug messages I have put for Encryption cache are not getting displayed in the server logs. How do I view those messages ?

Comment: I don't see why would take make a difference. Anyway, make sure that in Servers view > Worklight Development Server > Server Configuration > Logging, the logging level is set appropriately. You can use WL.Logger.info as well as set the logging leve to INFO and you should see it in the server  logs.

Comment: I am working with the remote server, not the embedded server in worklight studio. Now I have the below line of code put at certain conjecture's in java script. I am not able to see this in the server logs. 

WL.Logger.debug("Encrypted cache succesfully opened");

Will i see this message if i change the logging level on the server to debug as per your comment ?

Comment: JavaScript WHERE? Client or Adapter?

Comment: Its on the client side

Comment: If it's in the client side then why are you looking at the server side? again, open LogCat when the device is connected with a USB cable. If you want to send logs to the server from your client, then read about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808706/worklight-send-client-logs-to-server and the Knowledge Center.

Answer (score 0):

If you are Referring to Client-side Log Capture

You can use worklight Console

**During development**

- Developers should make liberal and reasonable use of the client-side
  logger APIs.
- Client-side logs that are uploaded to the embedded Liberty server in
  Worklight Studio are written to files under the clientlogs folder.
  This folder is a peer to the logs folder of the embedded server.
- Verifying this behavior is a good way to confirm the expected
  behavior of your usage of the API.

**In production**

- Logger configuration is controllable from the Worklight Console.
     Configuration that is retrieved from the server is used as an
     override of the locally set configuration. Clients revert to the
     pre-override configuration when the Worklight administrator removes
     the logger configuration and the client retrieves the instruction
     from the server.

> You don't need a Third-party app for it Worklight itself provides you this facility

[Client-Side Log Capture Info](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_client-side_log_capture.html)